# How do I get the character for a sigma field?

Tags: symbols

As the question says, like so[image]?

Comment: `( \Omega, \mathcal{F}, P )`?

Comment: @PauloCereda: Damn, you were quicker... `$...$`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Ducks are known for their math skills. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: But omit the $...$ apparently or have no idea of math - mode ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: uh-oh. `:)`

Comment: The symbol for the sigma field itself is the "script-F" letter, right? Your screenshot shows a *probability triple*: the event space `\Omega`, the sigma field `\mathcal{F}` of events defined on the event space, and the probability function `P` that assigns probabilities between 0 and 1 for all events in the sigma field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already pointed out by Paolo C. in a comment, `\mathcal{F}` is the way to go to typeset a calligraphic "F" in math mode. Now, there are quite a few math alphabets out there, and each one features a different shape for the calligraphic F.  Here are but a few possibilities:

[image]

The default is, on most TeX systems, Computer Modern. If one of the other glyphs strikes your fancy, you may want to look into how to load one or more math font package. Or, load the [mathalfa](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa) package with a suitable `cal=<xxx>` option. (In case you're curious, I obtained the 10 glyphs above by loading the `mathalfa` package with varying options.)

Comment: Nice overview..

Comment: Is it possible to generate the "F" next to "MathTime" without having to pay for it? I'd like to use it, but according to mathalpha's documentation, it seems that this is Mathtime Pro 2 script, which is a commercial (i.e., not free) font.

Comment: @Filippo - There's a "lite" subset of the full `mtpro2` package which is free of charge. However, in order to get the package's math fonts to work, the full (non-free) package must be downloaded. The price of the full package isn't exorbitant, though; depending on your typesetting needs, purchasing it might be an option for you, especially if you qualify for their academic pricing.

Answer (score 5):

I'd prefer `\mathscr{F}` to `\mathcal{F}` here.  Also, `mathtools` is nice because it takes care of a number of spacing issues and ensures that you always have matching brackets.

This loads a new command `\mathscr{F}` instead of changing the entire font, as in Mico's answer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}  % for paired delimiters 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}   % for script capitals
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\parens}()

\begin{document}
    $\parens{\Omega,\mathcal{F},P}$ or $\parens[\big]{ \Omega, \mathcal{F}, P }$ or
    $\parens{\Omega,\mathscr{F},P}$ or $\parens[\big]{ \Omega, \mathscr{F}, P }$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wait, I don't understand…why on earth should I write `\parens{stuff}` every time that I would otherwise write `(stuff)`? You certainly don't need `\big` delimiters here; the characters in parentheses don't even have ascenders or descenders!

Comment: Big was for illustration since it's a helpful feature of the structure.  As for parens versus brackets, the post answers that: especially in long documents with long formulas (and with careless coauthors) it pays to make sure that brackets are matched, in number, in type, and in size.  Plus I recall that there can be spacing issues without it in some circumstances.