# Changing default font for \mathcal in "Pages" equations (Mac)

Tags: fonts, mac, font-encodings

Sorry if this question is not too relevant to LaTeX.
LaTeX doesn't have good support for my language so I'm writing my paper in Mac's "Pages". I am using version 10.3.5 (7029.5.5) and using the "Insert Equation" feature to add my equations. I want this F:

[image]

But when I use the `\mathcal{F}` command (which gives me the F I want everywhere else) I get this super fancy RSFS F:

[image]

I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353317/how-do-i-get-the-character-for-a-sigma-field) where Mico says *"If one of the other glyphs strikes your fancy, you may want to look into how to load one or more math font package. Or, load the `mathalfa` package with a suitable `cal=<xxx> option.`"* But I don't know how I can do that for Pages.

Comment: Which language? It's likely that there’s some support in `babel` or `polyglossia`.

Comment: Here’s [the support page for that app.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202501) I don’t see any way to change the `\mathcal` font.

Comment: If you can use Pages, though, you can use LuaLaTeX and `unicode-math`, which should be able to support your language, and all of LaTeX.

Comment: Since your question is really about the `Pages` program, you may to (re)post it to https://apple.stackexchange.com/. There are currently 57 separate postings on that site that are tagged with both `pages` and `latex`.

Comment: @Davislor Farsi. I should have clarified that when I use packages, the output is fine but typing in the environment is a pain.

Comment: If you upgrade to LuaLaTeX, you can type in whatever Unicode input method, and even whatever text editor, you normally use. With the right `babel` commands, you won’t even have to add any special language tags.

Comment: The major reason to keep using legacy LaTeX is that, in 2020, some publishers (such as the arXiv) still require it. But, if you can use Pages, that’s not a requirement for you.